# NPM PM2, restart script

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'd like to create a NodeJS script that restart my current application. Is that possible?

My code :

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('my-command');
child.kill();
var exec          = require('child_process').exec;
exec('npm start');
```

Comment: The code you written works for me.

Comment: It restarts the application?

Comment: Sorry i fail to understand, you are killing the 'my-command' process and starting the 'npm'.  How does it restart the app ?